# Is there a need to formally register activities performed under an LLC?

Tags: limited-liability-company

I am considering establishing an LLC in North Carolina. The forms that I have seen for North Carolina just have contact information but no actual description of the LLCs activities. Is there a need to describe the activities performed under the auspices of the LLC? How is an activity legally performed under the LLC?

In terms of liability, how can it be clear that I was performing some activity via the LLC, and not myself personally?

Also if there is a better stack exchange site for this type of question please let me know. I looked around but was surprised to find that there was no business related Stack exchange site, at least as far as I could find.

Comment: We don't give legal advice here; talk to a lawyer

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a need to describe the activities performed under the
> auspices of the LLC?

No. Stating than an LLC can engaged in "any lawful activity" is typical.

> How is an activity legally performed under the LLC?

By not having the LLC engage in illegal activities like selling cocaine or arranging for contract killings or brokering endangered animal parts or laundering money.

> In terms of liability, how can it be clear that I was performing some
> activity via the LLC, and not myself personally?

In terms of contract liability, make the LLC the party to the contract and not you individually. Likewise, if LLC property has a certificate of title or is transferred by deed or a bill of sale, make the LLC the buyer. If you hire an employee, have an employment contract (even a very simple one) that names the LLC as the employer. If you sell something in packaging, put the LLC name on the packaging as the seller. If you have a website, put the domain in the LLC name and identify it as the LLC's website on the website. And, if the LLC is doing something that requires a license, get the license in the LLC name.

If you personally engage in tortious activity while engaged in LLC business (e.g. getting into a car accident that is your fault while on LLC business), both you and the LLC are liable. You can't escape liability for wrongful tortious or criminal activity you personally participate in simply because you are doing that while on LLC business.

Comment: How does this come into play when purchasing and writing off items? In theory I understand that the LLC can write off purchases as expenses if it is used for the business. But without an actual legal scope of activity for the business, how can the tax authorities make a clear distinction. For example if I start a dance studio LLC, the purchase of dance shoes would be a clear Business expense. But if I start a River rafting LLC, the purchase of dance shoes would clearly be unrelated. If I were to get audited, is this just at the discretion of the auditor?

Comment: @pixelearth good question - you should ask it.

Comment: @pixelearth that's the question you could ask us at the money@SE site :) Generally, in the US, unless you explicitly chose otherwise, LLCs are disregarded and are treated as you the person from tax perspective. So anything you can do on your Schedule C - you can do with the LLC. In fact, it will end up on that same Schedule C (unless you have multiple members).

Comment: If you are audited, the auditor can ask about it and you can try to explain why it is a valid expense. If you go into river rafting and your Secretary misheard it as “river dance” and purchased dancing shoes by mistake that is a valid expense - if the auditor believes it.